# DMing a Specific Person with Pinging Him

Tags: discord, discord.js, message, ping, dm

so today I was trying to make a bot DM a specific person by pinging him, for example: **!dm @potato hello**

By Using This:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'dm')) {

        let args = message.content.split(" ")[2];
        let user = message.mentions.users.first()

        if (!user) return message.channel.send("**Please mention a user**")
        
 if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('814454313438806016')) {
            return message.channel.send('You do not have the permissions to use this command.')
        }
        if (!args[0])
            return message.reply("Nothing to say?").then(m => m.delete(5000));

        if (args[0].toLowerCase() === "embed") {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setDescription(args.slice(1).join(" "))
                .setTimestamp()
                .setColor('WHITE');

            message.channel.send(embed);
        } else {
            message.channel.send('**Done**')
            user.send(args.join(" "));
        }
}
```

And SMH, it's not working, I hope you guys could help me

Console Link Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/10kzxie

Answer (score 0):

Tbh, there's not a lot of errors in your code, just a lil bit of problems. Use the following, if there are still problems, please comment!

```js
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'dm')) {
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/g);
    let member = message.mentions.members.first()
    if (!member) return message.channel.send("**Please mention a member**")

    if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('814454313438806016')) {
      return message.channel.send('You do not have the permissions to use this command.')
    }
    if (!args[0]){
      return message.reply("Nothing to say?").then(m => m.delete(5000));
    }

    if (args[0].toLowerCase() === "embed") {
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(args.slice(2).join(" "))
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor('WHITE');
      message.channel.send('**Done**')
      member.send(embed);
    } else {
      message.channel.send('**Done**')
      member.send(args.splice(1).join(" "));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Works But It's Sending the message with the command https://prnt.sc/10ol9ff

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, is this when your using an embed or message

Comment: Add me on discord and ill explain it to u N̷i̷g̷h̷t̷m̷a̷r̷e̷ ̷ Jeff#2616

Comment: Try the code above now, I have edited the code, it should work now!